Solid angle for rectangular detector
I was asked about how to calculate the solid angle for a detector consisting on two rectangular plates of the same dimensiones ($l\times w$) placed one above other a distance $d$ apart, like the bottom and top of a rectangular box and then calculate the solid angle for this arrangement.
Reading on internet I found this but here is one rectangular plate and I'm not sure it is right for my arrangement. Any help you can provide to me? Particularly I'm looking for articles or books where I can read about.
Thanks in advance. c:
